# Confused about 'word of'

Tags: grammar, phrase-meaning, phrases

I came across a sentence today:

***Our client said this would be our last deal, seeing as word of our plan got out.***

What does the phrase 'word of' refer to? Is it equal to ***'..., seeing as the detail/content/information of our plan got out'***?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Merriam Webster**:

> 4 a : **NEWS, INFORMATION** sent word that he would be late

"word [of something] [got out, was revealed, was made public etc.] is an idiomatic usage.

You can get word of something [by phone or in an email/mail]
You can also send word about or of something to someone.

- We got word he would be late for the party.
- We got word of his demise in the newspaper.